# Is it risky to use exceptions like this?

Tags: delphi, exception

I have the following function

```
function calculate(s:string):integer;
begin
  try
    strtoint(s);
    do_something;
  except
    result:=-1;    
  end;
end;
```

Is there any consequence of using exceptions like this?

Comment: Why would you think there would be any *risk* or *consequence*?

Comment: @KenWhite I use this function a lot, and I was wondering if it is going to affect any thing like memory or maybe crashing the app or even leading to miss management of memory by my app.

Comment: No, there's no chance of anything like that happening. You can make your code much cleaner, though, using something like `Result := StrToIntDef(s, -1); if Result <> -1 then...` or using David's suggestion.

Comment: `TryStrToInt()` woud be better than `StrToIntDef()` (particularly if `-1` is a valid number for the function to use), eg: `if TryStrToInt(s, Result) then do_something else Result := -1;`

Comment: @Remy: The code posted shows returning -1 in the `except` block, which would mean that it's not a valid number, wouldn't it? Or at least what was desired as the return value on failure?

Comment: @KenWhite: the **Result** is -1 on error, but that doesn't mean the **Input** can't be -1 (which is a valid numeric value). Since we don't know what `do_something` actually does with the input, we can't really judge one way or the other. But, `TryStrToInt()` is still better since it does not rely on any magic numbers, like `StrToIntDef()` does.

Comment: Using exceptions for flow control is arguably bad. A string not being an integer is nothing exceptional, that's why you should use Davids suggestion of using TryStrToInt(). https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: @RemyLebeau calculate would never return -1 but -1 is a valid input,@kenWhite -1 is a valid input but not a valid result,

Comment: @PieterB thanks it was very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the intent is to check the validity of the input string then there are better methods than an exception handler. To convert from string to integer and detect invalid input use [`TryStrToInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToInt):

```
var
  value: Integer;
... 
if TryStrToInt(s, Value) then
  Result := ...
else
  Result := -1;
```

This function returns `True` if the string can be converted to an integer, and if so that integer is returned via the second argument, an out parameter. Otherwise the function returns `False`. In your code you ignore the converted integer value but it is available if you need it.

This is to be preferred over an exception handler, in my view, because it is more explicit and concise. Not to mention avoiding the performance overhead of raising and catching an exception.

Of course, your code will detect failures other than an invalid string. One potential source for errors is your `do_something` procedure. If you really want to swallow any exceptions raised by that procedure then an exception handler is needed. However, I rather suspect that it is more likely that your original intent was to catch invalid string input only. In which case your code was incorrect.

Another source of errors is if `s` happens to be an invalid string variable. But if that happens then the entire basis of your program is pulled from under you and I personally don't think you should expect to handle such scenarios gracefully.

Part of the problem with advising you is that your code is probably not truly representative. For instance it does not appear to set the return value if the input is valid. And we don't know for sure what the intent of your exception handler is. I'm guessing that you mean to trap errors in the call to `StrToInt` but I cannot tell that for sure.

Comment: Whether this is appropriate or not depends heavily on the contract, which is not specified in the question.

Comment: @deltics I'm not sure I understand that comment. If you are referring to the contract that the input variable be a valid string, then I've never seen a contract that permits it not to be.

Comment: Changing the behaviour of the method such that only *one specific condition* yields -1 and all other exceptions are now unhandled is a *fundamental* change and only appropriate if the specification for the `calculate` method is known to require this (i.e. the current implementation is simply wrong).  Changing the behaviour on the basis of "style" without also refactoring all of the code that is dependent on the current behaviour is a recipe for broken code.  Correctness of code is not measured with "Style Points" alone.  Stylish **and** Correct is of course the goal.  :)

Comment: @Deltics Indeed. However, `TryStrToInt` does not raise exceptions. Ah, OK, I get it. The other function could do that though. That stems back to my original misreading of the question.

Comment: the return value is calculated in the do_something part if `s` is a valid integer (as I believe the test of strtoint would return)

Comment: the intent of the code is to return a -1 one if the do_something is not executed

Comment: OK, so the intent is exactly as I stated in the first pargraph

Answer (score 3):

It very much depends on the specification of the `Calculate` method.

If the specification stipulates that -1 is returned in the event of *any* and *all* exceptions then this is fine and (formatting issues aside) does the job as concisely as possible.

If the contract is only that the method returns -1 for invalid (non-numeric) strings then there is a potential issue that `DoSomething` itself might raise other exceptions (including possibly unrelated conversion errors) which will then be incorrectly handled, to yield -1 from the `Calculate` method (making it impossible to distinguish between invalid values of **s** and other errors.

In the latter case it would be more correct to handle the specific contract with respect to the string parameter in a way that avoids relying on an exception (since an error in this case is not "exceptional" but a specific input case to be handled) and allow exceptions from `DoSomething` to be handled by the caller, if appropriate.

To test for a valid numeric string you can use `TryStrToInt` and only call `DoSomething` if **s** is determined to be a valid integer.  Assuming that the result of the `Calculate` function is -1 for invalid inputs and the result of the `DoSomething` operation on the numeric value of **s** otherwise:

```
function calculate(s: String):integer;
begin
  if NOT TryStrToInt(s, result) then
    result := -1;
  else
    result := DoSomething(result);
end;
```

The use of **result** in this way is a matter of personal preference.  Some would argue that you should not use **result** for working storage like this and that you should use a separate local variable to hold the integer value of **s**, named accordingly:

```
function calculate(s: String): Integer;
var
  inValue: Integer;
begin
  if NOT TryStrToInt(s, inValue) then
    result := -1;
  else
    result := DoSomething(inValue);
end;
```

FWIW: I personally would favour the latter.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply go for something like this:

```
function calculate(s:string):integer;
begin
  result:=-1;
  strtoint(s);
  do_something;
  result:=.... <--- whatever value you want to return or maybe result:=do_something as Deltics shows
end;
```

Comment: the hall point of the exception is to handle the possibility of `s` being an invalid integer if I was sure that `s` is a valid integer type this question would not be asked in the first place.

Comment: @NasreddineAbdelillahGalfout: Then, this is not obvious at all from your code. This is what made Ken to ask you the first question and your response to his comment failed to raise this point, too. Then, David and Remy stepped in and clarified this for you.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I thought it was clear when I wrote the strtoint inside the try block.